# XAML compilaction dll search path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll, compilation

I have a WPF C# project in Visual Studio which depends on two nuget packages. The first package is log4net and the second one is package which contains more dlls and older version of log4net.

When I try to compile my project I get this error:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets(268,9):
>   error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'log4net, Version=1.2.9.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b32731d11ce58905' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

What I have tried:

1) Create a new empty project for WPF application, add references to mentioned nuget packages and compile it. I get the error as well. So the problem is not connected with another project or code in my solution.

2) Create a new empty wpf application project but without xaml files, add refereces etc. Compiletion works, only with warnining. Result is, that the problem is connected with xaml files.

When I double click on the error message it brings me to the MarkupCompilePass1 tag in Microsoft.WinFx.targets. I think that during compiling of xaml file it could not find the required dll.

I know that I can specify some dll redirections in app.config file. I did it and I checked that it is used in runtime. But it is used only in runtime.

My question: **Is it possible to specify the dll search path or something similiar for the compilation?**

More info:
I have tried one tool for analyzing dll loading, but it didn't helped me.

I have switch the log level of compiler to "verbose", but it also didn't tell me anything interesting. Lot of messages and suddenly the error message. No more explanation around it.

Visual Studio 2015, .NET 4.6.2

Comment: DLL versioning issues are never fun to deal with. The error is clearly linked to having two different version of log4net included with two different packages. Can you not use the stand-alone log4net package and use the older version that comes with the other package? Alternatively, you could get the owner/maintainer of the package that includes log4net to remove it from their nuget - they shouldn't be including something directly that they can reference as a package dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately both suggestions are not acceptable. I'm using the newer version of log4net in whole solution and in lot of other projects linked with this solution. The old version is used by dll supplied by big manufacturer of IP cameras.